# why is this appearing ?: clone.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, clone, getelementbyid

I've got this error:

> index.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: clone.getElementById is not a function
> at HTMLButtonElement.changeImg (index.js:29:11)
> changeImg @ index.js:29

It marks the line highlighted. I don't understand why. If somebody can help me I'll appreciate it.

```js
//captura de elementos:
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const templateImg = document.querySelector('.templateImg').content;
const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.imgContainer');

const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

let arrayImg = [
"/img/food1.jpg", 
"/img/food2.jpg", 
"/img/food3.jpg", 
"/img/food4.jpg", 
"/img/food5.jpg", 
"/img/food6.jpg", 
"/img/food7.jpg", 
"/img/food8.jpg", 
"/img/food9.jpg"
];

const changeImg = () => {

let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
   
//Crear clon del template:
const clone = templateImg.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
console.log(clone);
console.log(arrayImg[ran]);
//capturar elemento y modificar el src:
clone.getElementById("img").src = arrayImg[ran];

fragment.appendChild(clone);

   imgContainer.appendChild(fragment);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', changeImg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="StyleSheet" href= "style.css"  type= "text/css">
<title>Cambiador de imagenes</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    h1>Food and drink in Florianopolis</h1>
    <div class="imgContainer"><!--templateImg--></div>
    <button type="text" class="btn" id="btn">Change</button>
</div>

<template class="templateImg">
   <img id="img" src="/img/food1.jpg">
</template>

<script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to change the images inside the template modifying the `src`:

```html
<template class="templateImg">
    <img id="img" src="/img/food1.jpg">
</template>
```

When I use `querySelector`, the error is that the value I try to replace is null even though it's not, and with `getElementById`, I get that message that it's not a function.

Comment: Although this isn't your issue, you shouldn't be cloning something with an ID without changing the ID in the cloned object. Since closing duplicates the elements, you will be duplicating the ID and IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a "clone" with this code:

```
const clone = templateImg.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
```

that is a image element(see in console) and you for changing image src just need to use this code:

```
clone.src = arrayImg[ran];
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` is a method of `document` not of any HTML element.

What you want to use instead is `querySelector` which you can in fact use on elements.